# Exception safety in a self-contained application

Tags: c++, exception

In a self-contained application (as opposed to a library) I am led to believe that in terms of exception safety the aim should be "provide the [basic guarantee](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/059.htm) throughout".

Does that sound reasonable? Should we only worry about providing the strong and nothrow guarantees where they contribute to that aim?

Answer (score 1):

Your aim is to provide the strongest exception safety you can and only lower it if you have to or if not lowering it would be expensive.

The best exception safety you can provide is nothrow, but this is obviously hard to avoid at all times. There are some places where your code *should* throw, otherwise you're just avoiding exceptions in general.

Next, you should strive for the strong guarantee, but this can be expensive to implement. It often requires making excessive temporary copies to ensure that no observable state is affected during the operation of your function.

At a minimum, you should provide the basic guarantee. This usually isn't expensive to ensure, as you're just making sure nothing leaks. The smart pointer types can help you with that. That doesn't mean the basic guarantee is bad, but if you can do better you should.

Perhaps the aim would be better written as "provide *at least* the basic guarantee throughout but strive for the best guarantee you can get".

Comment: This is basically it- always give the best guarantee you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is best answered by the one writing the application. I have code that calls exit() to signal failure, which violates quite a few guidelines, but I think I can justify that decision in that particular case (a one-shot application, like a compiler). Actually, it doesn't even clean up resources but leaves that to the OS. On the other hand, if the standalone application was a long-living server app, the basic guarantee isn't even enough. Further, for library code, you generally don't have the necessary knowledge to determine where it is used, so you have to be careful.

In summary, I'd say you should try to provide strong/nothrow guarantees as a guideline, but you can make a (hopefully well-informed) decision to lower those requirements in a particular case.